# Pad missing data in a matrix with NA based on another matrix

Tags: r, matrix, data-manipulation, missing-data

I have two adjacency matrices where the second one has some missing data (that means these two matrices are of different square size) but how do I pad the missing data with NA in the second matrix?

Data below:

```
#first matrix
t1 = matrix(
  c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
  nrow = 4,  
  ncol = 4,        
  byrow = TRUE         
)
rownames(t1) <- c("a","b", "c", "d")
colnames(t1) <- c("a","b", "c", "d")

#second matrix
t2 = matrix(
  c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  nrow = 3,  
  ncol = 3,        
  byrow = TRUE         
)
rownames(t2) <- c("a","c", "d") #assume data from b are missing here
colnames(t2) <- c("a","c", "d")
```

Expected outcome for the second matrix:

```
  a  b  c  d
a 1  NA 1  0
b NA NA NA NA
c 0  NA 0  1
d 0  NA 0  1
```

I have a much larger dataset and so a more efficient approach will be appreciated@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If row and column names can be relied upon:

```r
t3 <- t1
t3[] <- NA
t3[rownames(t2), colnames(t2)] <- t2

t3
#    a  b  c  d
# a  1 NA  1  0
# b NA NA NA NA
# c  0 NA  0  1
# d  0 NA  0  1
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert Hacken. Concise and efficient!

Comment: @cliu Speaking of efficient.. I replaced the `ifelse()` that created the new matrix of `NA`s with a different approach which is faster. This won't probably matter in most cases but might in some.

Comment: Hi @Robert Hacken Sorry I just realized that the problem I have is a little different from this. Would you bother to take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73838452/pad-the-missing-data-with-na-for-two-matrices?

Comment: @cliu I see you already have an accepted answer there but I still felt like posting an alternative one.