# Pad the missing data with NA for two matrices

Tags: r, matrix, data-manipulation, missing-data

I have two square matrices where both of them have some missing data. I want to pad the missing data with NA in the two matrices

Data below:

```
#first matrix
t1 = matrix(
  c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
  nrow = 3,  
  ncol = 3,        
  byrow = TRUE         
)
rownames(t1) <- c("a","b", "c")
colnames(t1) <- c("a","b", "c")

#second matrix
t2 = matrix(
  c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  nrow = 3,  
  ncol = 3,        
  byrow = TRUE         
)
rownames(t2) <- c("a","c", "d") 
colnames(t2) <- c("a","c", "d")
#Expected outcome for the two matrices:
#first matrix
  a  b  c  d
a 1  0  1  NA
b 0  0  1  NA
c 1  0  1  NA
d NA NA NA NA

#second matrix
  a  b  c  d
a 1  NA 1  0
b NA NA NA NA
c 0  NA 0  1
d 0  NA 0  1
```

How do I achieve this? Preferrably the outcome is a list that contains these two NA-padded matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If row and column names will always be the same in each of the matrices (no hardcoded row/column names here) :

```r
nam <- union(rownames(t1), rownames(t2))
m <- array(dim=rep(length(nam), 2),
           dimnames=list(nam, nam))
lapply(list(t1, t2), function(x) {
  m[rownames(x), colnames(x)] <- x
  m
})

# [[1]]
#    a  b  c  d
# a  1  0  1 NA
# b  0  0  1 NA
# c  1  0  1 NA
# d NA NA NA NA
# 
# [[2]]
#    a  b  c  d
# a  1 NA  1  0
# b NA NA NA NA
# c  0 NA  0  1
# d  0 NA  0  1
```

Comment: Hi @Robert Hacken. Thanks for the code. Your code works better as I don't need to code the column and row names. Brilliant!

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of `.1` and `.2` in the output?

Comment: Yes, I added an alternative way of creating the initial matrix `m` in my answer that does not name the dimensions.

Comment: @jay.sf I wonder why the`table` approach is not a good practice. Will it cause the code to break in some situations?

Comment: @cliu There are common ways to initialize a `NA` matrix. The `table` approach is rather code art and hard to understand (and the list in the dimnames attribute is unusually named). I'm happy the answer now shows best practice :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` to find the matching columns and rows otherwise it will add a column or row with NA's. Using `lapply` to perform the operations on each matrix to generate the outcome as a list. You can use the following code:

```r
l <- list(t1, t2)

lapply(l, \(x) {
  # Your required columns and rows names
  colrown=c("a","b","c","d")
  # columns part
  coln=colnames(x)
  x=x[,match(colrown,coln)]
  colnames(x)=colrown
  # Rows part
  rown=rownames(x)
  x=x[match(colrown,rown),]
  rownames(x)=colrown
  return(x)
})
#> [[1]]
#>    a  b  c  d
#> a  1  0  1 NA
#> b  0  0  1 NA
#> c  1  0  1 NA
#> d NA NA NA NA
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    a  b  c  d
#> a  1 NA  1  0
#> b NA NA NA NA
#> c  0 NA  0  1
#> d  0 NA  0  1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data**

```
#first matrix
t1 = matrix(
  c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
  nrow = 3,  
  ncol = 3,        
  byrow = TRUE         
)
rownames(t1) <- c("a","b", "c")
colnames(t1) <- c("a","b", "c")

#second matrix
t2 = matrix(
  c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  nrow = 3,  
  ncol = 3,        
  byrow = TRUE         
)
rownames(t2) <- c("a","c", "d") 
colnames(t2) <- c("a","c", "d")

t1
#>   a b c
#> a 1 0 1
#> b 0 0 1
#> c 1 0 1
t2
#>   a c d
#> a 1 1 0
#> c 0 0 1
#> d 0 0 1
```

Comment: I did have to tweak your code a little bit but it worked for my larger datasets. So thank you! @Quinten